# How can you get a list of a type of object based on the type of another object when you can't use a generic?

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I'm trying to get a strongly-typed subset of a collection based on the type of an instance of a subclass passed into that function. I'm not sure this is possible but figured I'd ask.

Here's some pseudocode:

```cs
void DoSomething(UIElement child){

    var otherChildrenOfSameType = Children
        .OfType<WhatGoesHere>()  // What goes here?
        .Where(c => c != child);
}
```

Now normally, I'd just use generics, like this...

```cs
void DoSomething<TChild>(TChild child)
where TChild : UIElement {

    var otherChildrenOfSameType = Children
        .OfType<TChild>()
        .Where(c => c != child);
}
```

...but unfortunately I can't change the signature.

As mentioned above, I'm thinking this isn't possible, at least not in a type-safe fashion, because you need the type at compile-time which this doesn't provide.

I'm thinking the best I can do is this...

```cs
void DoSomething(UIElement child){

    var childType = child.GetType();

    var otherChildrenOfSameType = Children
        .Where(c => c.GetType() == childType && c != child);
}
```

...but of course this is just a collection of `UIElement` objects. It works, but I'm just trying to be more type-safe if you will. Is there a different way I'm not seeing?

Comment: Is the list of types it can be limited? You could use pattern matching and do something depending on the type.

Comment: That's interesting! Yes, it's limited.  However it's about 10 different types so I'm not really keen on giant switch statements.  I'm thinking of making them a list of 'Dynamic' objects so I can get at the non-common properties.

Comment: There is nothing type unsafe about the third code snippet. It's not like you need to return a collection of child's type, or anything like that.

Comment: Yeah, it's not that it's type-unsafe, it's just not strongly-typed to the specific subclass, only the base class. But then again, I don't need the subclass in here so this does work.  Just more verbose. My OCD doesn't like it however... lol... so used to `OfType<SomeType>()` and never realized/came across a case where I didn't have the type at compile time until tonight so I'm just whining. lol